# Does a Nuxt Vue app remain in SPA mode after initial hydration? (and how about robots/crawlers?)

Tags: single-page-application, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

Server Side Rendering (in Nuxt, but I think this is fairly universal) has been explained to me as:

> When using Nuxt SSR, you request an URL, and get sent back a
> pre-rendered HTML page. After loading, the browser starts the
> hydration code, at which point the static page becomes a Vue SPA application.

I presume (perhaps incorrectly) that regardless that you are now in SPA mode, if you request a new page (eg. you are on "blog/ten-blue-things" you follow a `NuxtLink` to "blog/ten-red-things") the browser sends a new request to the server for this page, and effectively break SPA-mode? Or am I wrong?

I really hope the answer is that it does **not** make a request. In my scenario all the required data is very likely already available, and if not the page would make an API call to get anything missing to dynamically render the new page "blog/ten-red-things". Fetching a pre-rendered page after the first fetch is wasteful in my scenario where everything is already on the client *(to clarify this further, this is a PWA offline-first app; I'm adding SSR for the SEO and social sharing of pages)*.

However, I also wonder that if it indeed does not make a request, does that (generally?) hold true for crawlers as well? I'd rather they DO make a separate request for each page in order for them to get the prerendered SEO-friendly version of the URL. If a crawler has js enabled, it may execute the hydration code, and then what?

- Can anybody clarify this perhaps?
- Does it matter for this anwser if instead of SRR we employ ISG (incremental static generation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not break the SPA mode, once you've SSR'ed and hydrated, the app stays as SPA. You can notice the fact that you don't have any "page reload" because you're doing a vue-router client-side navigation (as to oppose to a regular `a` link navigation).

The rest of the app will still be SSR'ed properly, you will not go back to the server meanwhile (as to oppose to Next.js).

They are several ways to debug all of this thanks to some devtools + trying to disable the JS/inspect the source code. But yeah, crawlers will properly parse the SSR'ed content.

PS: you can also choose what kind of rendering mode you want for a given page so if you want some to be SPA-only, you can. The rest could be SSR'ed (during initial render) + SPA after the hydration.

SSR or ISG will not make any impact regarding crawlers/SEO.
It works differently from SSR of course, but the rendering part will be the same regarding the markup. Only the "freshness" will be different.